# Java cannot create output file: access denied

Tags: java, permissions, fileoutputstream

I am trying to create a file then use it in a FileOutputStream. However by default the file is being created without read and write permissions, thus leading to an access denied error. This issue is only happening on my PC, and therefore I am confident that it is not code related. Are there any settings which can fix this problem please?

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
final OutputStream testStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Running the below code returns false:

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
f.canRead();
```

This is the error I am getting when trying to use the file in a FileOutputStream:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
```

Comment: No, there's no file created. It's throwing an exception when you're attempting to create it, meaning you don't have access to the location where you're trying to write it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I have just figured out that if I run the code as an administrator it works.

Comment: You don't have write access to the current working directory. Nothing to do with Java, and nothing to do with the file being 'created without read and write permissions'. It isn't created at all. The exception happens instead.

Comment: @ganninu93 Of course it works. Administrator has all the rights. However it would make more sense to run it as a regular user, writing to a directory where you're allowed to write.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. How can I give access to the regular user please?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Im running on Windows 10

Comment: `attrib -r .`, but only if run as administrator, and you may instead need to use the Properties window in Explorer. Question is now off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have write permission on the directory. 
Secondly always close streams in finally block.

Answer (score -1):

The might due to not closing the outputstream. You can try closing Outputstream at the end of the code like this.

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
final OutputStream testStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

//Other code goes here

testStream.close()
```

Comment: An exception in a constructor is not caused by failing to do something with the object that wasn't constructed because of the exception.